# Resource Recommendations for Rigorous Analyses of Impact Mechanics and Terminal Ballistics

Tags: resource-recommendations, collision, material-science, projectile

I'm an engineer with close relations in body-armor-wearing occupations and am interested in better understanding the extent to which the physical separation of hard body armor plates from the surface of a user's skin affects backface deformation.

I am looking for recommendations on references (especially books) that develop analytical methods for modeling impact mechanics and terminal ballistics. It seems as though there are a few well-known references on the subject, such as *Terminal Ballistics* by Rosenberg and Dekel as well as *Armour* by Hazell. I'd appreciate any other recommended references, **especially those that might not fall explicitly within the field.**